# Send Email Via IMB Notes using VBA - Sent message saves in drafts?

Tags: vba, email, lotus-notes

I am using the following code to send an email via IBM Notes using VBA.

Code:

```
Sub SendEmail()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False


Application.CutCopyMode = False


'Define Variables
Dim Ref As String
Dim TrueRef As String

Dim Attachment As String
Dim WB3 As Workbook
Dim WB4 As Workbook
Dim Rng As Range
Dim db As Object
Dim doc As Object
Dim body As Object
Dim header As Object
Dim stream As Object
Dim session As Object
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim j2 As Long
Dim server, mailfile, user, usersig As String
Dim LastRow As Long, LastRow2 As Long, ws As Worksheet
LastRow = Worksheets(1).Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row  'Finds the last used row


'Define Depot
Ref = Range("F" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Value

    If Ref = "WED" Then
    TrueRef = "WED"
    Else
    If Ref = "WSM" Then
    TrueRef = "WES"
    Else
    If Ref = "NAY" Then
    TrueRef = "NAY"
    Else
    If Ref = "ENF" Then
    TrueRef = "ENF"
    Else
    If Ref = "LUT" Then
    TrueRef = "MAG"
    Else
    If Ref = "NFL" Then
    TrueRef = "NOR"
    Else
    If Ref = "RUN" Then
    TrueRef = "RUN"
    Else
    If Ref = "SOU" Then
    TrueRef = "SOU"
    Else
    If Ref = "SOU" Then
    TrueRef = "SOU"
    Else
    If Ref = "BRI" Then
    TrueRef = "BRI"
    Else
    If Ref = "LIV" Then
    TrueRef = "LIV"
    Else
    If Ref = "BEL" Then
    TrueRef = "BEL"
    End If
    End If
    End If
    End If
    End If
    End If
    End If
    End If
    End If
    End If
    End If
    End If


    If Ref <> "" Or TrueRef <> "" Then ' FailSafe



'Start a session of Lotus Notes
Set session = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")
'This line prompts for password of current ID noted in Notes.INI
Set db = session.CurrentDatabase
Set stream = session.CreateStream
' Turn off auto conversion to rtf
session.ConvertMime = False



'Email Code

'Create email to be sent

Set doc = db.CreateDocument
doc.Form = "Memo"
Set body = doc.CreateMIMEEntity
Set header = body.CreateHeader("Subject")
Call header.SetHeaderVal("Food Specials Delivery Tracker: The Status of Your Issue Has Changed (" & Range("N" & ActiveCell.Row).Value & ")")

'Set From
Call doc.ReplaceItemValue("Principal", "Food Specials <mailto:Food.Specials@Lidl.co.uk>")
Call doc.ReplaceItemValue("ReplyTo", "Food.Specials@Lidl.co.uk")
Call doc.ReplaceItemValue("DisplaySent", "Food.Specials@Lidl.co.uk")



'Set From
Call doc.ReplaceItemValue("Principal", "Food Specials <mailto:Food.Specials@Lidl.co.uk>")
Call doc.ReplaceItemValue("ReplyTo", "Food.Specials@Lidl.co.uk")
Call doc.ReplaceItemValue("DisplaySent", "Food.Specials@Lidl.co.uk")


'To
Set header = body.CreateHeader("To")
Call header.SetHeaderVal("supplychain-" & TrueRef & "@lidl.co.uk")



'Email Body
Call stream.WriteText("<HTML>")
Call stream.WriteText("<font size=""3"" color=""black"" face=""Arial"">")
If Hour(Now) > 12 Then
Call stream.WriteText("<p>Good afternoon,</p>")
Else
Call stream.WriteText("<p>Good morning,</p>")
End If
Call stream.WriteText("<p>Reference: " & Format(CDate(Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row).Value), "DDMMYY") & " - " & Range("C" & ActiveCell.Row).Value & " - " & Range("D" & ActiveCell.Row).Value & "</p>")
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("N" & ActiveCell.Row).Value = "Issue Complete" Then
Call stream.WriteText("<p>Your recent issue has been marked as complete.</p>")
Else
Call stream.WriteText("<p>The status of your recent issue has changed.</p>")
End If



'Insert Range
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row & ":K" & ActiveCell.Row & ", N" & ActiveCell.Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
Set Rng = Selection
Call stream.WriteText(RangetoHTML(Rng))
Cells(1, 1).Select

Call stream.WriteText("<BR><BR><p><a href=""G:\WH DISPO\(3) PROMOTIONS\(18) Food Specials Delivery Tracking\Food Specials Delivery Tracker.xlsm"">Click here to view your issue on the Delivery Tracker now.</a></p></br>")

'Signature
Call stream.WriteText("<BR><p>Kind regards / Mit freundlichen Gr&#252;&#223;en,</p></br>")
Call stream.WriteText("<p><b>Lidl UK Food Specials Team</b></p>")

Call stream.WriteText("<table border=""0"">")
Call stream.WriteText("<tr>")
Call stream.WriteText("<td><img src=""http://www.lidl.co.uk/statics/lidl-uk/ds_img/layout/top_logo2016.jpg"" alt=""Mountain View""></td>")
Call stream.WriteText("<td><img src=""http://www.lidl.co.uk/statics/lidl-uk/ds_img/assets_x_x/BOQLOP_NEW%281%29.jpg"" alt=""Mountain View""></td>")
Call stream.WriteText("</tr>")
Call stream.WriteText("</table>")


Call stream.WriteText("</font>")
Call stream.WriteText("</body>")
Call stream.WriteText("</html>")

Call body.SetContentFromText(stream, "text/HTML;charset=UTF-8", ENC_IDENTITY_7BIT)

doc.Save True, False
Call doc.PutInFolder("Delivery Tracker Email Notifications")


Call doc.Send(False)

session.ConvertMime = True ' Restore conversion - very important


'Clean Up the Object variables - Recover memory
    Set db = Nothing
    Set session = Nothing
    Set stream = Nothing
    Set doc = Nothing
    Set body = Nothing
    Set header = Nothing

    'WB3.Close savechanges:=False

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

'Email Code



Else ' Otherwise - FailSafe



'Start a session of Lotus Notes
Set session = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")
'This line prompts for password of current ID noted in Notes.INI
Set db = session.CurrentDatabase
Set stream = session.CreateStream
' Turn off auto conversion to rtf
session.ConvertMime = False



'Email Code

'Create email to be sent

Set doc = db.CreateDocument
doc.Form = "Memo"
Set body = doc.CreateMIMEEntity
Set header = body.CreateHeader("Subject")
Call header.SetHeaderVal("Food Specials Delivery Tracker: The Status of Your Issue Has Changed (" & Range("N" & ActiveCell.Row).Value & ")")

'Set From
Call doc.ReplaceItemValue("Principal", "Food Specials <mailto:Food.Specials@Lidl.co.uk>")
Call doc.ReplaceItemValue("ReplyTo", "Food.Specials@Lidl.co.uk")
Call doc.ReplaceItemValue("DisplaySent", "Food.Specials@Lidl.co.uk")



'Set From
Call doc.ReplaceItemValue("Principal", "Food Specials <mailto:Food.Specials@Lidl.co.uk>")
Call doc.ReplaceItemValue("ReplyTo", "Food.Specials@Lidl.co.uk")
Call doc.ReplaceItemValue("DisplaySent", "Food.Specials@Lidl.co.uk")


'To
Set header = body.CreateHeader("To")
Call header.SetHeaderVal("food.specials@lidl.co.uk")



'Email Body
Call stream.WriteText("<HTML>")
Call stream.WriteText("<font size=""3"" color=""black"" face=""Arial"">")
If Hour(Now) > 12 Then
Call stream.WriteText("<p>Good afternoon,</p>")
Else
Call stream.WriteText("<p>Good morning,</p>")
End If
Call stream.WriteText("<p><b>Error: The below email was not delivered to the RDC.</b></p><br>")
Call stream.WriteText("<p>Reference: " & Format(CDate(Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row).Value), "DDMMYY") & " - " & Range("C" & ActiveCell.Row).Value & " - " & Range("D" & ActiveCell.Row).Value & "</p>")
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("N" & ActiveCell.Row).Value = "Issue Complete" Then
Call stream.WriteText("<p>Your recent issue has been marked as complete.</p>")
Else
Call stream.WriteText("<p>The status of your recent issue has changed.</p>")
End If



'Insert Range
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row & ":K" & ActiveCell.Row & ", N" & ActiveCell.Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
Set Rng = Selection
Call stream.WriteText(RangetoHTML(Rng))
Cells(1, 1).Select

Call stream.WriteText("<BR><BR><p><a href=""G:\WH DISPO\(3) PROMOTIONS\(18) Food Specials Delivery Tracking\Food Specials Delivery Tracker.xlsm"">Click here to view your issue on the Delivery Tracker now.</a></p></br>")

'Signature
Call stream.WriteText("<BR><p>Kind regards / Mit freundlichen Gr&#252;&#223;en,</p></br>")
Call stream.WriteText("<p><b>Lidl UK Food Specials Team</b></p>")

Call stream.WriteText("<table border=""0"">")
Call stream.WriteText("<tr>")
Call stream.WriteText("<td><img src=""http://www.lidl.co.uk/statics/lidl-uk/ds_img/layout/top_logo2016.jpg"" alt=""Mountain View""></td>")
Call stream.WriteText("<td><img src=""http://www.lidl.co.uk/statics/lidl-uk/ds_img/assets_x_x/BOQLOP_NEW%281%29.jpg"" alt=""Mountain View""></td>")
Call stream.WriteText("</tr>")
Call stream.WriteText("</table>")


Call stream.WriteText("</font>")
Call stream.WriteText("</body>")
Call stream.WriteText("</html>")

Call body.SetContentFromText(stream, "text/HTML;charset=UTF-8", ENC_IDENTITY_7BIT)

doc.Save True, False
Call doc.PutInFolder("Delivery Tracker Email Notifications")


Call doc.Send(False)

session.ConvertMime = True ' Restore conversion - very important


'Clean Up the Object variables - Recover memory
    Set db = Nothing
    Set session = Nothing
    Set stream = Nothing
    Set doc = Nothing
    Set body = Nothing
    Set header = Nothing

    'WB3.Close savechanges:=False

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

'Email Code





End If






Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

The codes working and the email is being sent. I am also choosing to save a copy of the sent email in a folder called Delivery Tracker Email Notifications.

However, these emails also seem to be appearing in the drafts folder - Even though they have been sent.

Please can someone explain/show me where i am going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The saved copy is still a draft because it hasn't been sent yet.  You need to save it after you send it.

I.e., change this:

```
doc.Save True, False
Call doc.PutInFolder("Delivery Tracker Email Notifications")

Call doc.Send(False)
```

To this:

```
Call doc.Send(False)
doc.Save True, False
Call doc.PutInFolder("Delivery Tracker Email Notifications")
```